# System.InvalidOperationException with form validation

Tags: c#, blazor

I am currently running preview 9 of .net core 3.   I am trying to get the form valdation working.  I am copying the example from [forms and validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

## model

```
namespace BlazorListPreview9.Model
{
    public class ItemModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Name is too long.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## form

```
@page "/FormsValidation"
@using BlazorListPreview9.Model;

<EditForm Model="@itemModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="@itemModel.Name" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private ItemModel itemModel = new ItemModel();

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnValidSubmit");
    }
}
```

## error

> WASM: System.InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'BlazorListPreview9.Components.EditForm' does not have a property matching the name 'Model'.

Comment: They are nothing wrong on your code, it should run on both serverside or blazorwasm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a class definition called EditForm in 'BlazorListPreview9.Components' ? I think not, right ?

I have a feeling this is somehow related to installation, package reference, and the like.

Please try this code and report whether it works:
Note that instead of providing the Model you can provide an EditContext object. The end result is the same...

```
@page "/FormsValidation"
@using BlazorListPreview9.Model;

<EditForm EditContext="@editContext" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="@itemModel.Name" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private EditContext editContext;

    private ItemModel itemModel = new ItemModel();

     protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    this.editContext = new EditContext(itemModel );
   }
    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnValidSubmit");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...